# nodes are being added at some unknown locations in my binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

To learn implementation of binary search tree,
I created a class `bst` and am facing problem in its `add_node_private` function.

bst.cpp -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#include "bst.h"
// bst constructor
bst::bst() {
  root = nullptr;
}
// methods of binary search tree
bst::node* bst::create_leaf(int a) {  // creating a leaf with key
  node* leaf = new node;
  leaf->key = a;
  leaf->left = nullptr;
  leaf->right = nullptr;
  return leaf;
}
// adding a leaf to the tree
void bst::add_leaf(int k) {
  bst::add_leaf_private(k, root);  // just calls the private function 
                                   // providing it with root
}
void bst::add_leaf_private(int k, node* ptr) {
  if (ptr == nullptr) {
    ptr = create_leaf(k);
    cout << k << " added\n";
    return;
  }
  if (k > ptr->key) {
    cout << "went left of " << ptr->key << endl;
    add_leaf_private(k, ptr->right);
  }
  if (k < ptr->key) {
    cout << "went right of " << ptr->key << endl;
    add_leaf_private(k, ptr->left);
  }
  if (k == ptr->key) {
    cout << "key " << k << " already exists\n";
  }
}
```

bst.h

```
#ifndef _BST_H
#define _BST_H

class bst
{
    private:
    struct node{
        int key;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };
//private methods
void add_leaf_private(int k,node* ptr);
//void print_private(node* ptr);

public:
node* root=nullptr;
//bst constructor
bst();
//public methods

node* create_leaf(int k);
void add_leaf(int k);
//void print();
};


#endif // _BST_H
```

When I add leaves, I output shows that they were added (like this- `5 added`)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "bst.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    bst b1;     
    int tree_keys[]{50,70,21,4,32,64,15,51,14,100,83,2,3,70,87,90};
    for(int x: tree_keys){
        b1.add_leaf(x);
    }
    cout<<"root"<<b1.root<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't see any statement `went left of ...` or `went right of ...` which I was expecting. And later I checked and found out even after adding a bunch of nodes, I have my `root==nullptr` and I don't know where the nodes were being added then?

Comment: did you step through with yr debugger. Anyway please show the calling code

Comment: show `bst.h` to make example complete and compilable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake of using `ptr` in the function `add_leaf_private` by value. I should have passed it by reference as I intend to change it in the function. Replacing `ptr` with `&ptr` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you are never updating root. Its always nullptr

you need

```
void bst::add_leaf_private(int k, node* ptr) {
  if (ptr == nullptr) {
    ptr = create_leaf(k);
    root = ptr;
    cout << k << " added\n";
    return;
  }
```

Comment: I think,  for the first node, `root` would be a `nullptr` and should be updated to `create_leaf(k)`.

Comment: well create_leaf does not update root at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not getting it. I would be very grateful if you would explain a bit more.